# javac not always executing on start of leiningen project

Tags: java, clojure, compilation, interop, leiningen

Currently, I have a project that until recently was behaving as expected.
 I have a custom java class for interfacing with a clients JMS server, to meet requirements that current clojure libraries could not.
 I had my project set up to compile the .java file on start or build so that any changes I made would be included, and if the .class file was accidentally removed it would not crash. 
Recently though when I start the project with `lein repl`, it does not always compile the class, and if it does it places it in the target/classes directory instead of the directory specified with `-d`.
 My project file is as follows with minor changes for anonymity:

```
(defproject my/project "0.0.2-SNAPSHOT"
  :description REDACTED
  :url "http://comapny-name.com"
  :license {:name "company-name Commercial license"
            :url "http://www.company-name.com"}
  :min-lein-version "2.4.3"
  :java-opts ["-Xmx5g" "-server" "-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"]
  :exclusions [org.clojure/clojure]
  :dependencies [[my/lib1 "2.1.9"]
                 [my/lib2 "1.2.16" :exclusions [com.taoensso/encore]]
                 [my/lib3 "1.1.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/data.zip "0.1.1"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.10"]
                 [com.codahale.metrics/metrics-graphite "3.0.2"]
                 [com.palletops/leaven "0.3.1"]
                 [com.github.kyleburton/clj-xpath "1.4.5"]
                 [metrics-clojure "2.5.1"]]
  :java-source-paths ["java/src"]
  :javac-options ["-target" "1.7" 
                  "-source" "1.7" "-Xlint:-options" 
                  "-cp" "resources/jars/w3thinclient.jar:resources/jars/clojure-1.6.0.jar:resources/jars/log4j-1.2.17.jar:resources/classes/WebLogicListener.class"
                  "-d" "resources/classes"]
  :profiles {:dev {:source-paths ["dev"]
                   :dependencies [[org.clojure/tools.namespace "0.2.11"]]
                   :plugins [[lein-package "2.1.1"]
                             [lein-marginalia "0.7.1"]]}
             :prod {:source-paths ["prod"]
                    :main prod}}
  :prep-tasks ["javac" "compile"]
  :resource-paths ["target/classes"]
  :plugins [[lein-package "2.1.1"]
            [lein-immutant "2.0.1"]]
  :immutant {:war {:resource-paths ["war-resources"]}
             :nrepl {:port REDACTED
                     :host REDACTED
                     :interface REDACTED
                     :start? true}}
  :hooks [leiningen.package.hooks.deploy leiningen.package.hooks.install]
  :package {:skipjar true
            :autobuild true
            :reuse false
            :artifacts [{:build "with-profile prod immutant war --name=%p%v%t" :extension "war"}]}
  :uberjar-exclusions [#"(?i)^META-INF/[^/]*\.SF$"] ;; Eliminate the signing code from the uberjar
  :repositories ^:replace [["nexus" {:url "http://nexus.company-name.localnet:REDACTED/nexus/content/groups/public"}]])
```

My java file is located in java/src. I am using Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.7.0_79 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM.

This project.clj setup had used to compile the .class file to resources/classes on each startup, without issue until recently.